# System.Net.Http.HttpClient caching behavior

Tags: c#, wcf, couchdb, wcf-web-api

I'm using HttpClient 0.6.0 from NuGet.

I have the following C# code:

```
var client = new HttpClient(new WebRequestHandler() {
    CachePolicy =
        new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.CacheIfAvailable)
});
client.GetAsync("http://myservice/asdf");
```

The service (this time CouchDB) returns an ETag value and status code 200 OK. There is returned a Cache-Control header with value must-revalidate

Update, here are the response headers from couchdb (taken from the visual studio debugger):

```
Server: CouchDB/1.1.1 (Erlang OTP/R14B04)
Etag: "1-27964df653cea4316d0acbab10fd9c04"
Date: Fri, 09 Dec 2011 11:56:07 GMT
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
```

Next time I do the exact same request, HttpClient does a conditional request and gets back 304 Not Modified. Which is right.

However, if I am using low-level HttpWebRequest class with the same CachePolicy, the request isn't even made the second time. This is the way I would want HttpClient also behave.

Is it the must-revalidate header value or why is HttpClient behaving differently? I would like to do only one request and then have the rest from cache without the conditional request..

(Also, as a side-note, when debugging, the Response status code is shown as 200 OK, even though the service returns 304 Not Modified)

Comment: Caching is not trivial. Can you update your post with the request headers of the both calls?

Comment: I don't think request headers are that necessary in this case. As I'm confused why HttpClient even does that second call (compared to HttpWebRequest, which only does one call).

Comment: It's normally ONLY the headers that matters in terms of what the server is sending you.

Comment: Oh you meant response headers? I'll update those..

Comment: What is the value of of the must-revalidate header that you refer to?

Comment: The service would return the same thing it the request was the same. Therefor have a look at the request headers in both cases. There must be a difference between the two.

Comment: Asken, the problem isn't what the response are. It's that with HttpWebRequest there **is no** second request. And I would like to HttpClient behave the same. Only ask one time..

Comment: Updated the question with the headers..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Both clients behave correctly.

[`must-revalidate` only applies to *stale* responses](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.4).

> When the must-revalidate directive is present in a response received by a cache, that cache MUST NOT use the entry *after it becomes stale* to respond to a
>   subsequent request without first revalidating it with the origin server. (I.e., the cache MUST do an end-to-end revalidation every time, *if*, based solely on the origin server's Expires or max-age value, *the cached response is stale*.)

Since you do not provide explicit expiration, [caches are allowed to use heuristics to determine freshness](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.2.2).

Since you do not provide `Last-Modified` caches [do not need to warn the client that heuristics was used.](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.2.4)

> If none of Expires, Cache-Control: max-age, or Cache-Control: s- maxage (see section 14.9.3) appears in the response, and the response does not include other restrictions on caching, *the cache MAY compute a freshness lifetime using a heuristic*. The cache MUST attach Warning 113 to any response *whose age is more than 24 hours* if such warning has not already been added.

The response [age is calculated based on `Date` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.2.3) since `Age` is not present.

If the response is still fresh according to heuristic expiration, caches may use the stored response.

One explanation is that `HttpWebRequest` uses heuristics and that there was a stored response with status code 200 that was still fresh.

Comment: Thank you for the correct answer. I accepted it. This made things much more clear to me!

Answer (score -2):

Answering my own question..

According to http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.4 I would say that 
a "Cache-Control: must-revalidate" without expiration states that the resource should be validated on every request.

In this case it means a conditional GET should be done every time the resource is made. So in this case System.Net.Http.HttpClient is behaving correctly and the legacy (Http)WebRequest is doing invalid behavior.

Comment: This is not correct, the spec doesn't say that. The correct answer [has been given by Hans Malherbe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9228743/795861)