# C# HttpClient stale check

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am working on improving performance for a high number of small payload web requests using HttpClient in .NET 4.5. I have found that for http clients in some other programming languages a performance tip is to disable "stale connection check", which is a check to see if the server has terminated a keep-alive connection (see e.g. [Stale_connection_check](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html#Stale_connection_check)). So my questions are:

1. Does C# HttpClient do such a stale connection check?
2. If so, can it be disabled?

Comment: AFAIK, the default `HttpClient` class has no keepalive or stale connection check. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: Staleness is part of the W3 spec... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445770/system-net-http-httpclient-caching-behavior http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.4